# JQuery Plugin extraneous code

Tags: jquery, plugins

Just confused as to what this snippet below means:

```
;(function(global, factory) {
    'use strict';
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['jquery'], function($) {
            return factory($, global, global.document, global.Math);
        });
    } else if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
        module.exports = factory(require('jquery'), global, global.document, global.Math);
    } else {
        factory(jQuery, global, global.document, global.Math);
    }
})(typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : this, function($, window, document, Math, undefined) {
    //plugin code below
});
```

I see it a lot at the top of jQuery Plugins, but never really understood as what the purpose was, or if it was needed. Could some please help clarify? Thanks!

Comment: Is there any part in particular which is confusing you?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The whole snippet is actually confusing me